# Apache with php-fpm: how do I increase the file upload size for a particular vhost?

Tags: php, apache

I'm setting up an apache vhost. The vhost is using php7.4-fpm to process php requests.

I'd like to set the file upload size (and of course the max post size) to allow larger uploads for this particular apache vhost.

I don't want to set the file upload / max post sizes globally for all vhosts.

How do I customize the setting for just this one particular vhost?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/configuration.file.per-user.php

Answer (score -2):

Set the value of `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in your php.ini file to the desired values. Keep in mind `post_max_size` must be greater than or equal to `upload_max_filesize`

See more about those values [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) and [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size).

Changing `php_value upload_max_filesize` and `php_value post_max_size` in your .htaccess may also help.

Comment: php.ini settings are applied to all vhosts. I'd like to create a setting for one particular vhost.

Comment: @bob Then update the .htaccess file as I have previously mentioned. This affects individual vhosts.

Comment: `php_value` is only available within `.htaccess` when running PHP as an Apache module. OP is using PHP-FPM

Comment: Zach, you didn't mention .htacccess. Just php.ini. The other thing to consider is that I've turned off overrides.